# Spring ServletFileUpload iterator return empty list

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, netflix-zuul, netflix-ribbon

I developed a system with microservice architecture with spring boot(1.5.9) framework, I used zuul and ribbon in the gateway pattern.
In order to upload large files, I disabled multipart upload as below:

```
application.yml
spring:
  http:
    multipart:
      enabled: false
      max-request-size: -1
      max-file-size: -1
```

As I know, because of preventing to process the multipart request by spring, we should disable spring multipart request resolver.
In the next step, I increased Ribbon timeouts and zuul timeouts:

```
gateway.yml
ribbon: #LoadBalancer
  ReadTimeout: 20000
  ConnectTimeout: 20000
zuul: #Gatway Proxy
  ignoredServices: '*'
  set-content-length: true
  #prefix: /api
  host:
    connect-timeout-millis: 20000
    socket-timeout-millis: 20000
```

Uploader code is like below:

```
DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
factory.setRepository(new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")));
factory.setSizeThreshold(0);
factory.setFileCleaningTracker(null);

//Create a new file upload handler
ServletFileUpload uploader = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory());

//Parse the request
FileItemIterator iter = uploader.getItemIterator(httpServletRequest);
while (iter.hasNext())
 {
 ...
 }
```

I using below URL in order to upload files:

```
example.com/zuul/serviceName/upload
```

As explained in spring document we need to add zuul prefix to URL in order to bypass zuul filter and I did it.
But it only works for small files, When I trying to upload large files,`FileItemIterator` is empty `iterator`.

I tested everything and after 2 days passed I could not fix the problem!

Comment: Do you have the following header " Transfer-Encoding: chunked " ? If yes, try removing and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

From the official documentation -

> **Uploading Files through Zuul** -
>
> If you use @EnableZuulProxy, you can use the proxy paths to upload
>   files and it should work, so long as the files are small. For large
>   files there is an alternative path that bypasses the Spring
>   DispatcherServlet (to avoid multipart processing) in "/zuul/*". In
>   other words, if you have zuul.routes.customers=/customers/**, then you
>   can POST large files to /zuul/customers/*. The servlet path is
>   externalized via zuul.servletPath. If the proxy route takes you
>   through a Ribbon load balancer, extremely large files also require
>   elevated timeout settings, as shown in the following example:

```
application.yml

hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds: 60000
ribbon:
ConnectTimeout: 3000
ReadTimeout: 60000
```

> Note that, for streaming to work with large files, you need to use
>   chunked encoding in the request (which some browsers do not do by
>   default), as shown in the following example:

```
$ curl -v -H "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" \
-F "file=@mylarge.iso" localhost:9999/zuul/simple/file
```

---

For large files (10M or more) upload, you have to add the /zuul prefix to the upload path. You can also use zuul.servlet-path to customize the prefix.

Suppose zuul.routes.microservice-file-upload=/microservice-file-upload/**

You could try bypassing the Spring DispatcherServlet and use Zuul as is your intention. If http://{host}:{port}/upload is the path of your file-upload, you can use Zuul's http://yourhost:port/zuul/your-service/upload path to upload large files.

Also, can you try ignoring the following header "Transfer-Encoding: chunked " and see if it helps.